# Azure functions and persist token cache file

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-ad-msal

I have an HTTP triggered function (.NET 3.1 TLS, running not from zip package), that connects to my personal OneDrive and dropping files.
To minimize authentication prompts I used this approach to serialize token cache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=custom#simple-token-cache-serialization-msal-only

On localhost it works great, but it is not so good while running function on Azure - the cache file is lost quite often.
I put in on `Path.GetTemporaryPath()`. Not sure which location is the best for such purpose. However the cache seems to be bound to a computer that created the file: when I use cache file, created on my localhost and uploaded to Azure, then using of such file shows errors around getting account details / enumeration.

Any ideas how to get this fixed by minimal cost? My app is using only one token: for my, personal, OneDrive.

Comment: I don't know much about this subject, but in general we like when people provide a full listing of all exception details, preferably with the code where it is triggered. Also, Stack Overflow is generally not going to filter answers by cost, as how much something costs depends on a number of factors.

Comment: Use durable functions and persist the token to a durable entity

Comment: Thanks, that might be a good option. I also just realized, that the code from the link encrypts the file with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata . So I'll try to not encrypt it , because it limits the decryption to one profile/machine. Then I can try to store 'byte[]' as durable entity.

Comment: I've tested it and durable state didn't helped much :-( After more or less one hour of iddle  state , the state of class got cleared and I needed to authenticate again ;-( I'll try Azure storage blob..

Comment: You are running in a serverless environment. Each invocation of your function potentially runs on a  different VM, as a result any locally stored state is lost. For persistent storage, you should switch to azure storage or some other durable store like a database or durable functions store.

Answer (score 1):

The final solution is:

- remove `ProtectedData` from code from the sample custom token serialization helper, because it encrypts the file with current profile or machine
- save  `args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV` to Azure Storage Blob and read it later.

So I've made changes in code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=custom#simple-token-cache-serialization-msal-only to the following:

EnableSerialization:

```
string cstring = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
string containerName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TokenCacheStorageContainer");
        try { bcc = new BlobContainerClient(cstring, containerName); } catch { }
        if (!bcc.Exists())
        {
            bcc = (new BlobServiceClient(cstring)).CreateBlobContainerAsync(containerName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        tokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
        tokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
```

BeforeAccessNotification:

```
lock (FileLock)
        {
            var blob = bcc.GetBlobClient("msalcache.bin3");
            if (blob.Exists())
            {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                blob.DownloadToAsync(stream).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

AfterAccessNotification:

```
if (args.HasStateChanged)
        {
            lock (FileLock)
            {
                // reflect changesgs in the persistent store
                (bcc.GetBlobClient("msalcache.bin3")).UploadAsync(new MemoryStream(args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3()),true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
```