# Custom token cache serializer MSAL.NET

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, token, azure-ad-msal

I want to use azure function and to have custom cache provider which will access to my azure storage where I will deposit tokens and refresh tokens.

Then this cache provider will be used for MSAL.NET and further authentication and authorization.

Is it possible to do it?

Because default cache serializer works within some .json files and stuff, Im not sure how this will be implemented with azure functions?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69002173/azure-functions-and-persist-token-cache-file